# How to repeating one row data in Oracle report?

Tags: plsql, report, reporting, oraclereports

i have repeating data for my table in the report design.i don't know how to display one row data from repeating data.
Anyone know about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

select distinct emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status
from YourTable

Use columns you required after distinct statement.

Comment: im not using the sql but in my report design. i don't know how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the layout items. You need to have your fields inside a repeating frame. Then, in the property inspector, make sure the "Source" under "Repeating Frame" references the group from the data model you are after.